# Hide features on Disqus 2012

Tags: styles, disqus

Is there a way to hide certain features from a Disqus 2012 panel? I can't seem to find any regulations for this on the Disqus site, but there's also no mention of how to do it. What I would like to hide/deactive in particular are:
- The "Star this discussion" link
- Subscribe (to email) link
- The add to RSS feed link
- The "Share this discussion" link

These features are unnecessary for the site that I'm working on and I'd prefer to keep the design as simple as possible. The iframe where the Disqus panel is brought in seems to ignore my own CSS stylesheets; setting one of the elements to display: none seem to have no effect, even with jQuery after the document is ready.
Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We load Disqus in an iframe, and thus styles cannot be forced upon the embed's markup. We do pull the font style/color, and the anchor color to help adapt it to the site it's embedded on, but we don't allow removal of any elements.

We do this to promote consistency and we've seen much better overall engagement as a result. We do understand that certain elements aren't appropriate for every site, but they have a very deliberate purpose within the Disqus ecosystem.

Comment: Thanks for the input Bryan. Are you part of the Disqus team? 
I wish there was a lighter version to choose from, with just the comment functionality and no rating or subscription features.

Comment: +1 for this. I agree completely. It's a shame that Disqus updated their system and is forcing this change on their users. I suspect you'll see some folks moving away from using Disqus as a result.

Comment: BTW, the star icon of Disqus is making users confused. Some of them thought the star was ther so they could rate the content of the page. Maybe removing the icon will be less invasive.